# Custom rollback attribute for IO operations for unit test methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, io

I have Rollback attribute for test methods that testing methods that using database transactions:

```
  public class RollbackAttribute : Attribute, ITestAction
  {
      private TransactionScope transaction;
      public void BeforeTest(TestDetails testDetails)
      {
          transaction = new TransactionScope();
      }

      public void AfterTest(TestDetails testDetails)
      {
          transaction.Dispose();
      }

      public ActionTargets Targets
      {
          get { return ActionTargets.Test; }
      }
  }
```

Is there any way to create similar attribute for methods which working with IO(create folder) operations?

Comment: If your create folder logic relies on relative paths, you can create a new folder for your SetUp method, have your test method work within this folder and your teardown recursive delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, file I/O implementation is not using transactions, so you can't rollback them. The best what you can do is writing your own mechanizm for that.

I will not copy others article but [HERE](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31270/A-Transactional-Repository-Implementation-in-NET) you have interesting example how to implement own transactional repository.

What is more interesting I found nuget package with implementation: [LINK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TxFileManager/)

Here you have usage example:

```
// Wrap a file copy and a database insert in the same transaction
TxFileManager fileMgr = new TxFileManager();
using (TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Copy a file
    fileMgr.Copy(srcFileName, destFileName);

    // Insert a database record
    dbMgr.ExecuteNonQuery(insertSql);

    scope1.Complete();
}
```